# The debugger never stops at breakpoints in a learning task

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class ProcessDeliveryOrders {

    public static DeliveryOrder findFirstOrder(List<DeliveryOrder> orders) {
        return new DeliveryOrder();  // Breakpoint.
        // write your code here
    }

    public static void printAddressesToDeliver(List<DeliveryOrder> orders) {
        System.out.println(); // Breakpoint.
        // write your code here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<DeliveryOrder> orders = Stream.iterate(1, i -> scanner.hasNextLine(), i -> i + 1)
                .map(i -> scanner.nextLine().split("\\|"))
                .map(parts -> new DeliveryOrder(
                        Long.parseLong(parts[0]), parts[2], LocalDate.parse(parts[1])))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(findFirstOrder(orders));  // Breakpoint.

        printAddressesToDeliver(orders);
    }
}

class DeliveryOrder {
    private final long orderId;
    private final String address;
    private final LocalDate deliveryDate;
    // there are even more fields: customer name, phone, products info, etc

    public DeliveryOrder() {
        this.orderId = -1;
        this.address = "No address";
        this.deliveryDate = LocalDate.MIN;
    }

    public DeliveryOrder(long orderId, String address, LocalDate deliveryDate) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.address = address;
        this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
    }

    public static Comparator<DeliveryOrder> getComparatorByDeliveryDate() {
        return Comparator.comparing(DeliveryOrder::getDeliveryDate);
    }

    public long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public LocalDate getDeliveryDate() {
        return deliveryDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        DeliveryOrder that = (DeliveryOrder) o;
        return address.equals(that.address) &&
                deliveryDate.equals(that.deliveryDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(address, deliveryDate);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return orderId + "|" + deliveryDate + "|" + address;
    }
}
```

This is a learning task.

To run it I enter this into the console:

Sample Input:

```
1|2021-09-03|112 Mammoth Street, Colorado Springs, CO 80911
2|2021-09-05|369 Woodside Court, Troy, NY 12180
3|2021-09-02|837 Bowman Street, Helena, MT 59601
4|2021-09-03|112 Mammoth Street, Colorado Springs, CO 80911
```

**Problem**

The debugger never reaches any of the three breakpoints marked in the code.
Without stopping on each of these breakpoints I can't understand the task and proceed.

Could you help me understand:

1. Why the debugger never reaches any of these breakpoints?
2. How to cope with this problem?

Comment: "The debuger"? Which debugger/IDE are you using?

Comment: add an "empty line" to input!(?) / hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to signal `! scanner.hasNextLine()`)

Comment: The code works for me, I could set a break point on the line `System.out.println()` in the main method.  You'll have to provide more details if for us to give you an answer.

Comment: After setting the breakpoints, did you run the program in debug mode? (It's a mistake I've been known to make. I click on the "run" icon instead of the "debug" icon.)  A more likely possibility is the program flow never reaches the set breakpoints. Try setting breakpoints at earlier locations, and use one of the "step-by-step" tools to follow the flow of the program.

Comment: After looking at Old Dog's comment and my own "answer" something that occurs to me is that `System.in` never actually closes.  Thus the `Scanner` never stops reading.  So you might never hit break points because you never reach the code which is after the part that reads input.  `StringReader` which I used below does close input for `Scanner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300961/the-debugger-never-stops-at-breakpoints-in-a-learning-task/76301027#comment134550097_76300961):

> The `StringReader` that I used here to debug your code closes the input to `Scanner`.  `System.in` never actually closes.  Thus you never actually reach the code that is after the part that reads input.  You might try this version, it'll help you reach those statements.

Something that might help is your input might be in question.  Typing all of what you have there is pretty complicated and might be error prone.

If you use a string inside the program as your input, it's reproducible for you and for us also.  Then we can all be assured that we are seeing the same issues with the code.

For example, add some test vectors to your code:

```
class ProcessDeliveryOrders {
   
   static String testVectors = "1|2021-09-03|112 Mammoth Street, Colorado Springs, CO 80911\n" +
"2|2021-09-05|369 Woodside Court, Troy, NY 12180\n" +
"3|2021-09-02|837 Bowman Street, Helena, MT 59601\n" +
"4|2021-09-03|112 Mammoth Street, Colorado Springs, CO 80911";
```

To do this I literally just copied the strings you have in your question and pasted them in between the quotes of a string literal `""`.

Then just use that string as "input" in your program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new StringReader( testVectors ) );

    List<DeliveryOrder> orders = Stream.iterate(1, i -> scanner.hasNextLine(), //... etc.
```

Now your code works exactly the same way for everyone, and we can all debug exactly the same problems.